# Detect the main order based on sub-lists

Tags: code-golf, sorting

The question is simple but the answer maybe not!

suppose that you have the following lists that all of them are ordered (not consecutive):

```
x = ['one', 'two', 'four']
y = ['two', 'three', 'five']
z = ['one', 'three', 'four']
```

as you can see there is a logic in each of the above lists for example in `x` we have the following order that is true `'one'<'two'<'four'` and also for other sub lists.

So the main list contain all the unique elements from preceding lists that contain `['one','two','four','three','five']` and the task is to find the main ordered list :

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

im not looking for a comprehensive or general answer! because it has not a general answer and it all depend on the number of sub-lists!

So whats your idea for this problem or problems like this?

Comment: `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']` is not 'the' main ordered list, `['one', 'two', 'three', 'five', 'four']` is valid as well. And you didn't specify if strict weak ordering is applicable.

Comment: @orlp no its not, i say already that sub-lists are ordered and you must find the main ordered list!

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: You said that the main order __is based on sub-lists__. If the order instead is determined by the values themselves, your entire question makes absolutely no sense and is trivial.

Comment: @Kasra Could you specify the way in which the order of the main list is to be inferred from the orders of the parts?

Comment: @FUZxxl check out the edit!

Comment: @orlp i add more explain on question, pls check out the edit!

Comment: @Kasra Then explain where in your lists it is said that `'four' < 'five'` and not `'five' < 'four'`.

Comment: @orlp it doesn't and this is the point of the question you need to find it by the relations between other lists

Comment: @Kasra Sorry, I don't understand your question, and I think it's ill-defined. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @orlp you can real my answer hope that it becomes helpful!

Comment: @Kasra Please tell me why `'five' < 'four'` stands in conflict with the constraints imposed by the lists in the question resp. why that can't be the case.

Comment: @Kasra Here's an explanation for what everyone's been telling you: In your example, the first list states that 1<2<4, or that 1<2, 1<4, and 2<4. The second one states that 2<3, 2<5, and 3<5. The last one states that 1<3, 1<4, and 3<4. Now we know from the sublists that 1<2, 1<3, 1<4, 2<3, 2<4, 2<5, 3<4, and 3<5. If we have [1,2,3,5,4], it states that **1<2**, **1<3**, **1<4**, 1<5, **2<3**, **2<4**, **2<5**, **3<4**, **3<5**, and 5<4. The bolded rules contain all of the ones taken from the sublists, so it still matches, even though _you're_ looking for [1,2,3,4,5] (which also matches).

Comment: Better not try to think this is a logic puzzle that you can "and ...!" while you are coding. From what I have understood, your reference answer is nowhere like a correct one (and it isn't a complete program either, and is not valid for code-golf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you might want to use a topological sorting algorithm. This procedure runs in O(*n*) where *n* is the sum of the number of elements in each list. Create a directed graph where each node is one of the distinct elements in the input lists. For each pair of elements adjacent in one of the element lists, add an edge between these two elements in the graph from the lesser element to the greater. Finally, topologically sort that graph.

Comment: Yes you are close, and this idea could be done with combinations! like my answer but i think using graphs is more efficient!

Comment: @Kasra you should not be encouraging non-answers. If you are interested in just the algorithm (or optionally code), remove code-golf tag

Answer (score 0):

## Python (182)

I think this might be a bit too long. I might try my hand at a J version of the same algorithm.

```
from itertools import*
def f(i):
 o=[]
 while len(i)>1:i=[a for a in i if a];o+=[a[0]for a,b in combinations(i,2)if a[0]==b[0]];[j.pop(0)for j in i if j[0]==o[-1]]
 o+=i[0]
 return o
```

### Example:

**Input:**

```
i = [['one', 'two', 'four'],
     ['two', 'three', 'five'],
     ['one', 'three', 'four']]
print f(i)
```

**Output:**

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Comment: Can you explain about your logic?

Comment: @Kasra Sure. What this is doing, is taking the element that is in the first place in 2 or more lists, and removes it, until there are no more elements left.

Comment: Try ``[['one','two','four'], ['two','three','four'],['two','four','five']]``. I'm not sure what this question is really asking but an infinite loop in this case is probably not what you wanted. (Oh, unless you are thinking this code-trolling...)

Comment: @user23013 code-trolling ? What is this ? 2013 ? Its called underhanded now ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 115 bytes

Could probably use some `Thread`s here...

```
Sort[Union@##,Function[{a, b},Less@@Function[c,Mean[Flatten@DeleteCases[FirstPosition@c/@{##},_Missing]]]/@{a,b}]]&
```

Written as a pure function, used via `*code*[<first list>, <second list>, ...]`. I don't see how this is dependent on the number of lists. If there is any ambiguity about the order, it chooses a pseudorandom working case.